# PHP Echo post parameter surrounded by strings

Tags: php

I have a textbox named 'fname'. I need to echo out the input of this box inside double quotes on a another page.

User enters: Test123

```
returrns: "Test123"
```

so how can I do that with $_POST["fname"] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<?php echo('"'.htmlspecialchars ($_POST["fname"]).'"'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use:

```
echo "Hi how are you {$_POST['fname']} ? I am fine thanks";
```

If you want to use it in a string surrounded by letters, simply use curly brackets {}.

Put the $_POST['fname'] to curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

besides the one nyarathotep mentioned:

```
echo sprintf('"%s"', $_POST['fname']);
printf('"%s"', $_POST['fname']);
```

Comment: looks very neat, I especially like your second line! However, I would recommend encoding the HTML special characters, you wouldn't want to fall for an XSS attack, would you?

Comment: of course. but it depends for what or where he is using it. in either case specialchars might be not enough. so i leave it out, as it was not part of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
 echo '"' . $_POST["fname"] . '"';
```

Or

```
 echo "'" . $_POST["fname"] . "'";
```

of course if you want to you can replace ' and " with &quot; or &#039; in the code...